# Is there a Way to Set Up the Transform Minimums/Maximums of Constraints by Merely Moving the Owner and then Pressing Some Button?

Tags: interface, transforms, constraints

I find it counterintuitive to try to set the minimum/maximum transform limits of constraints by directly entering minimum/maximum values into the text fields for the owner of those constraints. It's as if Blender expects us to always know what the hard numbers are with regard to our object positions, whether in global space, local space or what have you. But it would be much less of a headache if I could merely move the owner of the constraint in the 3D Viewport, and then tag the new position as a minimum or maximum transformation value during constraint setup, without even necessarily knowing WHAT coordinate value that owner's visual position in space corresponds to. When setting up constraints, all I care about is the *apparent* range of motion for any owner. I don't care about the actual coordinates. Constraint setup always requires me to be directly conscious of the hard numbers of those coordinates. Now, maybe it's a good practice to be aware of them. But it would still be nice, for convenience's sake, if the UI allowed me to set the minimum/maximum transform values for a constraint instantly upon moving the owner in space. Is there an addon that provides this functionality?

Comment: You can see an object's or bone's existing transform by looking on sidebar item; you can copy text/number fields by hovering mouse and ctrl-c; you can paste fields by hovering mouse and ctrl-v.

Comment: Where exactly? Post an answer with a picture.